# Dead Code Warning in IF Statement

Tags: java, warnings

I don't know why eclipse warn me "Dead Code" in this code of mine:

```
    PreparedStatement p = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT name FROM user WHERE age = ? , city = ?");
    p.setInt(1, (String) parameters.get("age"));
    p.setString(2, (String) parameters.get("city"));

    if (p == null) {
        log.warn("User is not available");
        return results;
    }
```

the warning was in the log, can anybody tell me the reason of this? thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`p` can not be `null` at that point, simply because you already called `setInt` and `setString` on `p` and if it were `null` there, then it would have thrown a `NullPointerException`, thus never reaching your `if`.

Also note that according to [its documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement%28java.lang.String%29), `preparedStatement` can't ever return `null`. It can only return a valid statement or throw an exception. In the latter case your `if` will *also* not be reached. That fact, however, is *not* checked by the compiler (because a *broken* implementation of `prepareStatement` *could* theoretically return `null`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to do that `null` check before you call any method on `p`. If p is `null`, it will never reach that line.

Answer (score -1):

if `p` is `null` then in the second line itself there will be `NullPointerException' thrown.

change the code like below

```
PreparedStatement p = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT name FROM user WHERE age = ? , city = ?");
if(p != null){
    p.setInt(1, (String) parameters.get("age"));
    p.setString(2, (String) parameters.get("city"));
}else{
    log.warn("User is not available");
    return results;
}
```

or bring the `if loop` before using `p`

```
PreparedStatement p = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT name FROM user WHERE age = ? , city = ?");
if (p == null) {
    log.warn("User is not available");
    return results;
}
p.setInt(1, (String) parameters.get("age"));
p.setString(2, (String) parameters.get("city"));
```

Comment: I'd discourage using a `null` check here, because `prepareStatement` is documented not to return `null`. If you want error handling, you should catch the `SQLException` and handle that.

Comment: yes, thank you for all of your comments. now I've got it. the IF statement will never be reached because if p is null (although it won't, based on the documentation), it will return an Exception before getting in IF statement. and if p is not null, IF statement will never run.